# Why wont my php file output a form value using GET method?

Tags: php

// I want to be able to select a destination from a dropdown list, which will then take me to a page than shows data based on the destination selected. Once the user has clicked on a radio box and clicks submit, it will take them to a webpage that display the information that was selected. How do I create this webpage. Please look at nextpage.php, it doesnt echo the $all_values variable am I doing something wrong. Please help me?

here is my display.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","display3.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="to_city" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="Sydney">Sydney</option>
  <option value="Brisbane">Brisbane</option>
  <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
  <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my display3.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
td{

    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
</style>
<body>

<?php
$q = strval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mydb');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"flights");
$sql="SELECT * FROM flights WHERE to_city = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

?>
<form action="nextpage.php" method="GET">


   <?php
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Route_no</th>
<th>to_city</th>
<th>from_city</th>
<th>price</th>
<th>Confirm</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $all_values = $row['route_no'] .",".$row['to_city'].",".$row['from_city'].",".$row['price'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['route_no'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['to_city'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['from_city'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='Confirm' value='".$all_values."'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my nextpage.php

```
<?php

echo $all_values;
if($_GET['$all_values'])
{
echo $_echo['$all_values']; 

}
else{
    echo "No data submitted";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

$all_values doesn't exist in nextpage.php, so you can't use that var.

When your form method is 'GET', you can use the $_GET[ **input name** ] to get information you want.

For example:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['Confirm']; //Get value of the choosen 'Confirm' input
?>
```

Comment: How can I individually assign route_no , to_city, from_city, price to variables and call them on the nextpage.php. Your way allows to me to call all values as a single array what if I wanted to call each value individually?